# How is local determined in ToLocalTime()

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

When using [ToLocalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), how is local time determined?  Is local time from the server or the client?  My assumption would be the server running the application.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is the local time zone of the computer that code is running on.  In an ASP.Net application, the code runs on the *server* - so that's the time zone that it will return.

The behavior of this function is actually dependent on the `.Kind` property of the source value.  From the [MSDN link you gave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx):

- **Utc** - This instance of `DateTime` is converted to local time.
- **Local** - No conversion is performed.
- **Unspecified** -This instance of `DateTime` is assumed to be a UTC time, and the conversion is performed as if Kind were Utc.

This is non-obvious behavior.  You can read other related problems with the .net `DateTime` class [here](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) and [here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

A few other points:

- If you follow [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices), you will set the server's time zone to UTC.
- If you are trying to display time in the user's timezone, you'll have to use [one of these strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351529/634824).

Answer (score 9):

`ToLocalTime()`, in this case, executes on the server. Therefore the time is evaluated on the server, and it'll return the server time to the client.

Answer (score 4):

It is the local time on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Local here is the timezone of the machine that the function executes on.