# ASP.NET Core DateTime - ToLocalTime vs ConvertTime

Tags: c#, .net-core

What is the correct way of converting UTC DateTime to local time (CET)? Should I use `System.DateTime.ToLocalTime()` or `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()`? Are there any differences? Or are they just two methods internally calling each other?

Comment: It is difficult to give a simple answer to this.  If you decompile the code in mscorlib you can see how each are implemented and it is not a straightforward comparison

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both methods should work just fine, I don't think either one is more correct than the other.

The most obvious difference in their standard usage is that `System.DateTime.ToLocalTime()` uses a local timezone provided by the system, while `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()` uses whatever timezone you give it (e.g. you hardcode CET).

In both cases you should pay attention to the `Kind` property, which can sometimes ruin your day.

Anyway, you might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490463/how-is-local-determined-in-tolocaltime) and of course the MSDN documentation of both methods, which sums up their behavior quite well.