# How to get the client timezone id?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, timezone

I can able to get the timezone offset in javascript. But how to get the timezone(Asia/Kolkata) by using that offset.

Please help me on this.

Comment: See also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16526897/634824)

Answer (score 1):

Use http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

```
> var timezone = jstz.determine();
> timezone.name(); 
"Asia/Kolkata"
```

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the timezone name by using this javascript offset in server side.