# Getting Client's Timezone in GWT

Tags: gwt, browser, timezone, locale, frontend

My application is hosted at one place whose Timezone is "A". And user can login from anywhere. Let's say he/she logged in from place whose timezone "B". I want the timezone of User from where he/she get logged in. So I can display him dates in his/her timezone.

So is there any way to get that user's timezone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to detect users timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525617/how-to-detect-users-timezone)

Comment: See specifically [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16526897/634824) to that question.  While you tagged your question for GWT - the answers are the same.

Answer (score 2):

A way to retrieve the client's timezone is to use javascript code through a native JNI method, as following:

```java
private native int getClientOffsetTimeZone() /*-{
    return new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
}-*/;
```

Note that the getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time difference between UTC time and local time, in minutes.

For example, If your time zone is GMT+2, -120 will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

GWT has the `com.google.gwt.core.client.JsDate` library, which is a wrapper to the JSNI that Yeser mentioned. That library exposes the native JavaScript Date object, which allows you to use `getTimezoneOffset()`.

Answer (score 0):

From client, you can retrieve the timezone offset with `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` and pass it to your server then use this offset to create correct Dates.

Comment: If the date formatting is done on the client-side, you could also just exchange timestamps from UTC (`Date#getTime()` and `new Date(long)`)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer - That is true, but that's not what was asked.

Comment: @user2508244 - A time zone is not an offset.  Please read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  With the approach you are suggesting, the only guarantee you can make is for a single moment in time.  Offsets change, even in a single time zone.

Comment: @MattJohnson and that's why I didn't post it as an answer ;-)

Comment: But a timezone offset is used to create a timezone. This is from the timezone-js page at GitHub: https://github.com/mde/timezone-js <blockquote>dt_str_tz is a date string containing timezone information, i.e. containing Z, T or a timezone offset matching the regular expression /[+-][0-9]{4}/ (e.g. +0200). </blockquote>