# Laravel 5.3 : Setting time zones based on users location

Tags: php, timezone, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

We have small blog application in Laravel 5.3 in which  i need some suggestion about setting time stamps on the following features

1.Admin can able to send notifications to all users with current time stamp
 (server timezone is Asia/Calcutta) user will see all the notifications  based on their time zones.

2.Users can add posts along with their current time stamps , when other users  see that posts based on their time zones.

So what are the changes i need to do on the timezone settings in my application??

Answer (score 4):

You might have already found an answer to your 7 months old question. Anyway, I am just posting here what I did to get rid of different time zone issue.

First read [Timo Huovinen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc) answer.

In my application, user should manually set the timezone. Based on it, convert MySQL time to appropriate timezone before sending it to client.

You can use `convert_tz()` function to convert between timezones.