# How to set the default timezone to the user's local timezone in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to set default timezone to the user's local timezone, please find my code below:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
$currentHour = date('h:i');
```

My code works correctly, but only works only for Karachi; if user in other country it may not works.

Comment: You can't. PHP does not know much about your Client

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607444/4248328  And  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16529135/4248328

Comment: Are you suspecting it'll not work or you really know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a user's timezone on the server side, and you can only make a guess at it on the client side.

If you rely on getting the user's IP address then you could geolocate that and deduce a time.

The way this is usually done is by asking the user (when they register, for instance) what timezone they are in and then use this in your time calculations.

Or use this  **javascript solution**

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Comment: its return -300 but how can i use this for get time zone in php

Comment: if you want to pass timezone from client side to server side .. u should use ajax

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determine-a-users-timezone.. this will help u

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make timezone global and not fix to a single timzone then I guess you should use UTC timezone and there are two part of this one is for America and one for rest of the world.

[Hope this link will work. Click here to know more](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/setting-the-default-timezone-for-php-to-use)