# Setting TimeZone for OpenApi v3

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I'm testing my app using SpringDoc OpenApi v3, after a request I'm getting a response with headers of GMT dateTime.
I need it as UTC+3 zone. For example, the request was sent at 11:02:58, but in the picture you can see and actual header. How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [By using HTTP request how to get server's timezone not in UTC format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42296659/113116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates in HTTP headers are always expressed in GMT. See [RFC 7231 section 7.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.1) and [MDN article on the Date header format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date#syntax).

If the client needs that value as local time, the client needs to convert from UTC to local time themselves. For example, if you are developing a client application, you can use a date/time library to display timestamps in the user's local time.