# Formatting DateTime with a Timezone

Tags: php, datetime

I'm having some trouble getting time-zones to play nice on a client project.

I'm pretty sure I'm just too burned out to see what's right in front of my face...

I've got this line...

```
new DateTime(date('m/d/Y h:i a',$expDate), $timeZone);
```

I'm trying to get the date and time from this line of code to display on the website (or be used for other date calculations... like whether or not that date/time has passed, etc.) but I want it to use the timezone I specified...

I can do *this*:

```
date('M j, Y h:i a T',$expDate)
```

But it uses UTC for the timezone... which is why I built the DateTime() bit in the first place...

---

The default value for $timeZone is for EST ('America/New_York') since that's the time-zone my client lives in.

But they have listings for clients all over the US and Canada, so they have an option to set the time-zone to match their clients' location.

I just don't know how to make it actually *use* that time-zone when it's determining whether or not the expiration date (and time) has passed...

I need it to default to midnight on the expiration date in their client's time zone.

***Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.***

Comment: I must ask first, what's the client OS? Sometimes PHP can't play nice with it, especially with some Linux Distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for timezone formatting:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$today = new DateTime("now", $timezone);
$today_formatted = $today->format('M j, Y h:i a T');
```

Getting clients timezone must be done by JS and here is an answer that certainly will help you with that:

[How to detect user's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529135/2153274)

Comment: The client's timezone gets selected from a drop-down list, so I have the time-zone I want to use as a variable already -- it's not for the local time-zone of the visitor.