# Enable user local time in Woocommerce Cart and Checkout date time display

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-bookings

For a bookings website I have activated 'Timezones'. The visitor's local time should be displayed. In the booking form everything is working fine. The cart data ($start_time, $end_time) is not being displayed correctly when using the function below.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_cart_data_wc_bookings', 10, 2 );
function display_cart_data_wc_bookings( $item_data, $cart_item ){

    if ( ! empty( $cart_item['booking'] ) ) {

        $date_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_date_format', wc_date_format() );
        $time_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_time_format', wc_time_format() );
        $start_date = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_get_start_date_with_time', date_i18n(  $date_format, $cart_item['booking']['_start_date'] ) );
        $start_time = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_get_start_date_with_time', date_i18n(  $time_format, $cart_item['booking']['_start_date'] ) );
        $end_time = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_get_end_date_with_time', date_i18n(  $time_format, $cart_item['booking']['_end_date'] ) );
        $persons = $cart_item['booking']['_persons'];
        $ID = $cart_item['booking']['_booking_id'];

        echo '<dt class="titel datum">' . __('Date', 'woocommerce') . '</dt><dd class="data datum">' . esc_html( $start_date ) . '</dd>';
        echo '<dt class="titel tijdvak">' . __('Time', 'woocommerce') . '</dt><dd class="data tijdvak">' . esc_html( $start_time ) . ' - ' . esc_html( $end_time ) . '</dd>';
        foreach($persons as $person){
            echo '<dt class="titel personen">' . __('Persons', 'woocommerce') . '</dt><dd class="data personen">' . esc_html( $person) . '</dd>';
        }
        echo '<dt class="titel booking_id">' . __('Booking #', 'woocommerce') . '</dt><dd class="data booking_id">' . esc_html( $ID) . '</dd>';

    }
}
```

The output of $start_time and $end_time should be displayed in the visitor's local time. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LoicTheAztec: Thanks for the update. Still not working. I've updated the code based on file 'class-wc-booking-cart-manager.php':

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_cart_data_wc_bookings', 10, 2 );
function display_cart_data_wc_bookings( $item_data, $cart_item ){
    if ( isset($cart_item['booking']) && ! empty($cart_item['booking']) ) {

        // Get and set the user time zone
        $booking_data = $cart_item['booking'];
        if ( ! empty( $booking_data['_booking_id'] ) ) {
            $booking = get_wc_booking( $booking_data['_booking_id'] );
            if ( wc_should_convert_timezone( $booking ) ) {
                $timezone_data = array(
                    'name'    => get_wc_booking_data_label( 'timezone', $cart_item['data'] ),
                    'value'   => str_replace( '_', ' ', $booking->get_local_timezone() ),
                    'display' => '',
                );
            }
        }

        $date_format    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_date_format', wc_date_format() );
        $time_format    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_time_format', wc_time_format() );
        $start_date     = date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), $booking->get_start( 'view', true ) );
        $start_time     = date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ), $booking->get_start( 'view', true ) );
        $end_time       = date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ), $booking->get_end( 'view', true ) );
        $persons        = $booking_data['_persons'];
        $booking_id     = $booking_data['_booking_id']; 

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Booking #', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => esc_html( $booking_id ),
            'display'   => esc_html( $booking_id ),
        );

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Date', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => esc_html( $start_date ),
            'display'   => esc_html( $start_date ),
        );

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Start time', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => esc_html( $start_time ),
            'display'   => esc_html( $start_time ),
        );

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'       => __('End time', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => esc_html( $end_time ),
            'display'   => esc_html( $end_time ),
        );

        $count = 1;

        foreach($persons as $person){
            $item_data[] = array(
                'key'       => __('Person(s)', 'woocommerce') . $count,
                'value'     => esc_html( $person ),
                'display'   => esc_html( $person ),
            );
            $count++;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $timezone_data ) ) {
            // Add timezone to the end.
            $item_data[] = $timezone_data;
        }
    }

    return $item_data;
```

With this code step 1 to step 4 in your first comment are not necessary. Tested and it works!

Answer (score 2):

To enable the user time zone jQuery and ajax are necessary. Here are the following steps:

1. early enabling user WooCommerce session *( WC Session )*,
2. getting the user browser time zone *(time zone from user computer or device)*,
3. sending that timezone to php via ajax,
4. grab that time zone in the user WC Session ,
5. then use it in your code on date and time php functions as `date()`, `date_i18n()`, `time()`…

Once the user time zone is saved in WC Session, all the related code will be auto disabled *(as not needed anymore)*.

The code:

```
// Early enable customer WC_Session (if not done)
add_action( 'init', 'wc_session_enabler' );
function wc_session_enabler() {
    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
    }
}

// Get the browser user timezone and send it to php (Ajax)
add_action( 'wp_head', 'user_timmezone_js' );
function user_timmezone_js() {
    if( ! WC()->session->get('time-zone') ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.6/jstz.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined') 
            return false;

        var tz = jstz.determine();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
            data: ({
                'action': 'time_zone',
                'timezone': tz.name()
            }),
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Success: '+response);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// function that gets the Ajax data and save it to user WC Session
add_action( 'wp_ajax_time_zone', 'set_session_timezone' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_time_zone', 'set_session_timezone' );
function set_session_timezone() {
    if ( isset($_POST['timezone']) && ! empty($_POST['timezone']) ){
        WC()->session->set('time-zone', esc_attr($_POST['timezone']) );
        echo  WC()->session->get('time-zone');
    }
    die();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

> Then you will include the following to get and set the time zone:

> ```
> if( $timezone = WC()->session->get('time-zone') ) {
> ```

```
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
}
```

---

**Updated:**

Now your code is incorrect when using `woocommerce_get_item_data` as it's a filter hook and require **to return** filtered content *(not to echo html)*…

Try the following instead *(untested)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_cart_data_wc_bookings', 10, 2 );
function display_cart_data_wc_bookings( $item_data, $cart_item ){
    if ( isset($cart_item['booking']) && ! empty($cart_item['booking']) && ! is_admin() ) {
        // Get and set the user time zone
        if( $timezone = WC()->session->get('time-zone') ) {
            date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
        }
        $booking_data = $cart_item['booking'];
        $date_format  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_date_format', wc_date_format() );
        $time_format  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_time_format', wc_time_format() );
        $start_date   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_get_start_date_with_time', date_i18n(  $date_format, $booking_data['_start_date'] ) );
        $start_time   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_get_start_date_with_time', date_i18n(  $time_format, $booking_data['_start_date'] ) );
        $end_time     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_get_end_date_with_time', date_i18n(  $time_format, $booking_data['_end_date'] ) );
        $persons      = $booking_data['_persons'];
        $booking_id   = $booking_data['_booking_id'];
        
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Date', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => esc_html( $start_date ),
            'display'   => esc_html( $start_date ),
        );
        
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Time', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => esc_html( $start_time ),
            'display'   => esc_html( $start_time ),
        );
        
        $count = 1;
        
        foreach($persons as $person){
            $item_data[] = array(
                'key'       => __('Person', 'woocommerce') . $count,
                'value'     => esc_html( $person ),
                'display'   => esc_html( $person ),
            );
            $count++;
        }
        
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Booking #', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => esc_html( $booking_id ),
            'display'   => esc_html( $booking_id ),
        );
    }
    return $item_data;
}
```

---

Partially based on: [How to detect user's timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525617/how-to-detect-users-timezone/16529135#16529135)

Comment: Thanks for the respond, LoicTheAztec. Unfortunately the code is not working correctly. The displayed timezone is correct but the displayed time is not correct. I think it's because my Timezone Settings in Wordpress is 'Amsterdam'. Another problem: I can't access my dashboard anymore somehow after I added the code to my functions file. Any suggestions to solve the problems?

Comment: @PPP For me the code to get the local time works just fine This code alter the wordpress time zone (or the server timezone) on php functions like `date()` `date_i18n()`, `time()`, `strtotime()`… Now I haven't pay attention really to your code and the problem is that you are using `woocommerce_get_item_data` filter hook in a wrong way… I have made an update and it should solve your dashboard problem and more.

Answer (score 1):

Its little bit tricky, what we can do is always in back-end deal with UTC time format and from front-end convert the UTC time to local time

to convert the localtime you can find the [help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746249/get-user-timezone), hope this way you can archive your goal