# Detect Timezone of client using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, timezone

I am using ASP.NET Webforms to get the data of client. till now I figured out the IP address of client and the city & country of the client. I am trying to find a way of how to retrieve the time zone by using its IP Address or country name or city name. I have googled and couldn't find any appropriate answer as everyone talks about injecting javascript to get timezone.
My question is: Is there any way to find timezone of the client? If so then how?`

Comment: Please don't randomly turn words into bold or code for no reason - it makes it really hard to read.

Comment: @Kritner i have read many articles  stackoverflow, they all ask to inject javascript, but i want to work on c#. either it asks to get timezone from any link or something like that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in a reliable way purely with C#.  The HTTP spec does not provide any hints of the client's time zone.

You can *guess* at a client's time zone by using IP geolocation, and there are many free and commercial services that provide time zone information.  However there is only a limited degree of accuracy with such an approach.

Even with JavaScript, the current solutions can still only *guess* the client's time zone.  There are improvements happening for this with in the ECMAScript Intl API, but not all browsers fully implement that yet.  [See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625076/634824).

Ultimately, if you need to know the time zone of the client from your back end code, the best thing to do is to *ask the user*.   Provide a time zone picker somewhere in your application.

You may also find [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351529/634824) useful.

Comment: yeah, i saw those articles but they were very old threads, so i thought to ask it again wondering maybe there is a way programmers have discovered now :(

Comment: is there any way we can get time from internet by providing the city and country ? @Matt Johnson

Comment: I'm sure there are many services that provide such lookups.  Try http://ip-api.com. See this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824.  Note that in both cases, you're getting an IANA time zone ID.  To use with .NET, you need [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).

Comment: i have got timezone, i did this by using javascript, i couldn't use c#, now can i get time from the timezone i got? @Matt Johnson

Comment: As I said - You need [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) if you want to do it in C#.  If you want to stay in JavaScript, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) with the time zone addon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the **TimeZoneInfo Class**
It represents any time zone in the world.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, haven't tried this class. I'll try it now!

Comment: This won't help with detecting the client's time zone in a web app.

Comment: @Lakiel Wade it didn't helped as my time is 1:21 a.m and it returns 3:21 p.m